# css nested min-height layout

Tags: html, css, layout

I try to achieve a Layout with nested min-height divs and a sliding footer.

The problem of course is that die inner min-height div is not expanding to the full heights of the outer div because the outer divs height is set with min-height.

here is the html:

```
<div class="container">
    <section class="pos-container">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, voluptates, qui eos dignissimos quae nobis at provident voluptatum dicta nesciunt possimus iusto vitae nihil hic assumenda aspernatur quos vel necessitatibus.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, voluptates, qui eos dignissimos quae nobis at provident voluptatum dicta nesciunt possimus iusto vitae nihil hic assumenda aspernatur quos vel necessitatibus.</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Doloribus, voluptates, qui eos dignissimos quae nobis at provident voluptatum dicta nesciunt possimus iusto vitae nihil hic assumenda aspernatur quos vel necessitatibus.</p>
    </section>
</div>

<footer>
    i'm footer
</footer>
```

and the css:

```
body {
background-color: grey;
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
overflow-y: scroll; 
}

.container {
    z-index: 1;
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-color: pink;
    margin-bottom: 6em;
}

.pos-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 50em;
    min-height: 100%;
    margin: auto; 
    background-color: green;
}

footer {
    z-index: 0;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 6em;    
}
```

[**FIDDLE #1**](http://jsfiddle.net/dvh8Y/)
In this Fiddle the height of the inner div (green) is not expanding to the height of the outer div(pink).

[**FIDDLE #2**](http://jsfiddle.net/dvh8Y/1/)
Seems fixed if i set the height of the outer div from min-height to height but there is another problem if the height of the inner div is more than 100% as you can see in [**FIDDLE #3**](http://jsfiddle.net/dvh8Y/4/)

Is there any pure css solution for this problem?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Does making both if the divs height: 100% not do the trick? Or is that not what you're after?

Comment: Not quite. If i do that and the content of the inner div is heigher than 100%, the content overflows but the divs are not expanding. the overflow: auto attribute doesn't help because it creates a second scrollbar.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the height for `body` or make it `height:auto;`
Check this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/X4yuE/)**

CSS change

```
body{
  height:100%; // remove this and add below line
  height:auto; 
}
```

Comment: unfortunately that will not work either. if the content is not as heigh as 100% the outer and inner div will collapse to the height of the content, but they have to have at least a height of 100%. you can see what i mean if you change the height of body to auto in my Fiddle #1. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Comment: So you want the inner div to have min-height of 100%, ie even if there is less content?

Comment: yes. both the outer div and the inner div should have the min-height of 100% and expand if the content is longer.